# For loop within a for loop for iterating files of different extensions

Tags: shell, for-loop

Say I have 20 different files. First 10 files end with `.counts.tsv` and the rest of the files end with `.libsize.tsv`. For each `.counts.tsv` there are matching `.libsize.tsv` files.   I would like to use a for loop for selecting both of these files and run an R script for on those two files types.
 Here is what I tried,

```
#!/bin/bash
arti='/home/path/tofiles'
for counts in ${arti}/*__counts.tsv ; do
    for libsize in "$arti"/*__libsize.tsv ; do
        Rscript score.R  ${counts} ${libsize}
 done;
done;
```

The above shell script iterates over the files more than 200 times whereas I have only 20 files. I need the Rscript to be executed 10 times for both files. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do at the end of this script?

Comment: In the end, I need to execute the R script on each `counts` and `libsize`

Comment: "10 times for both files" so 20 iterations total? Hopefully the files are named with similar first parts, ie do you have `myFile.libsize.tsv` and `myFile.__counts.tsv` Then you only need 1 loop, strip out the extension from the variable returned by the loop and add it back in to 2 copies on your `Rscript` line, ie. `Rscript ${myF}.__counts.tsv ${myF}.__libsize.tsv`. Good luck.

Comment: The Rscript should only run 10 times. Hence, 10 iterations. So I think I need to be more clear here, for every `.count.tsv` file there is a matching `.libsize.tsv` is present therefore in total 20. Therefore, at the end the Rscript should only iterate 10 times

Comment: @user1017373, thanks, that helps. Would you edit that information into the question as well?

Comment: @Aaron, yes I have edited my question now. Please let me know is this clear enough?

Comment: Yes, that's clearer. Also, it's not clear why you're mixing bash and R; the looping easily be done within R. Is that a possibility or are you perhaps for some reason not able to edit the R script? If not, this is really a bash question, not R.

Comment: Well, I need to use this bash. I do not wanna edit R. This is a part of testing something. however, I need to use bash to run a Rscript.

Comment: Ah, let's take the R tag off this then.

Comment: You can accept an answer when your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

I tried the following and it helped me,

```
for sam in "$arti"/*__counts.tsv ; do
      filebase=$(basename $sam)
      samples=$(ls -1 ${filebase}|awk -F'[-1]' '{print $1}')
        Rscript score.R ${samples}__counts.tsv ${samples}__libsize.tsv
 done;
```

For someone looking for something similar :)

Answer (score 3):

I started typing up an answer before seeing your comment that you're only interested in a bash solution, posting anyway in case someone finds this question in the future and is open to an `R` based solution.

If I were approaching this from scratch, I'd probably just use an R function defined in the file that takes the two file names instead of messing around with the `system()` calls, but this would provide the behavior you desire.

```
## Get a vector of files matching each extension
counts_names <- list.files(path = ".", pattern ="*.counts.tsv")
libsize_names <- list.files(path = ".", pattern ="*.libsize.tsv")

## Get the root names of the files before the extensions
counts_roots <- gsub(".counts.tsv$", "",counts_names)
libsize_roots <- gsub(".libsize.tsv$", "",libsize_names)

## Get only root names that have both file types
shared_roots <- intersect(libsize_roots,counts_roots)

## Loop through the shared root names and execute an Rscript call based on the two files
for(i in seq_along(shared_roots)){

  counts_filename <- paste0(shared_roots[[i]],".counts.tsv")
  libsize_filename <- paste0(shared_roots[[i]],".libsize.tsv")

  Command  <- paste("Rscript score.R",counts_filename,libsize_filename)
  system(Command)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Construct the second filename with `${counts%counts.tsv}` (remove last part).

```
#!/bin/bash
arti='/home/path/tofiles'
for counts in ${arti}/*__counts.tsv ; do
    libsize="${counts%counts.tsv}libsize.tsv"
    Rscript score.R "${counts}" "${libsize}"
done
```

EDIT:
Less safe is trying to make it an oneliner. When the filenames are without spaces and newlines, you can risk an accident with

```
echo ${arti}/*counts.tsv ${arti}/*.libsize.tsv | xargs -n2 Rscript score.R
```

and when you feel really lucky (with no other files than those tsv files in `$arti`) make a bungee jump with

```
echo ${arti}/* | xargs -n2 Rscript score.R
```

Comment: Thanks, I have another solution posted below :)

Comment: Your solution is the same idea, using both `basename` and `awk` is slower. In this case the performance won't matter, it will be important when you want to loop through large files and do something for each line.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `list.files` in base? This will allow you to use all files in the folder.

```
arti='/home/path/tofiles'
for i in list.files(arti) {
  script
}
```

Comment: The files I need are of two different extensions. Say I have file that ends with `counts.tsv`and `libsize.tsv` these files needed to be selected separately for the Rscript. Hence, your solution won't work.

Comment: @user1017373: This is almost certainly going to be the right tool to use, though. Perhaps you'll need to separate the list somehow after you get it? Please clarify the question, it's not clear how with 10 files of each type, you want the script to run only 10 times. There's something you're not telling us...

Comment: @Aaron, Thanks for the comment. Yes, for instance, I have 10 samples with `counts.tsv` files and a matching `libsize.tsv` file. Therefore, at the end I need only 10 ierations, however in the folder i have 20 files

Answer (score 1):

See whether the below helps.

```
my_list = list.files("./Data")
counts = grep("counts.tsv", my_list, value=T)
libsize = grep("libsize.tsv", my_list, value=T)

for (i in seq(length(counts))){
  system(paste("Rscript score.R",counts[i],libsize[i]))
}
```

Comment: This seems like a mix of bash and R and so wouldn't actually run; am I missing something?

Comment: The idea was to bring both the files simultaneously inside the for loop. Editing the answer.